# How to create a Dell drivers backup CD for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, backup

I have a Dell N5050 laptop with Windows 7 on it. I want to create driver CD for it as at the time of purchase the dealer/shop didn't give me one. So I want to create one just in case of format as a Rescue CD through which i could easily set up my Windows with all the necessary drivers.

I have gone through the [Dell.com/support](http://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsd1/product-support/servicetag/8TG7NP1/drivers) for the drivers but can't decide as to which one should be downloaded.(34 drivers in total).

[image: Total no of drivers available after entering the service tag.]

Also can I request Dell for the Driver CD for my model?

Note:-

1.As i don not have the dell backup and recovery software on my System i cannot use that.(I tried doing the backup for Windows 8.1 using the dell backup software but that was not helpful)

2.The process is being performed through the Windows Backup

Comment: I suggest you try one of the myriad solutions you get when you google `How to create a drivers backup CD for windows 7`

Comment: Most new laptops don't come with CDs (or DVDs) anymore. Dell Backup and Recovery is used to create rescue and recovery disks. Take a look at [Dell Backup and Recovery: Rescue Disk and Factory Backup](http://www.dell.com/support/article/in/en/indhs1/SLN151701/en?c=in&s=dhs&cs=indhs1&l=en) for more information.

Comment: @CharlieRB agreed but mine is a 2011 model laptop at which point they were supposed to give the driver CD.I don't have the dell backup and restore so i am doing Windows Backup.

Comment: @CharlieRB moreover i have already tried doing the Driver &utilities backup in a Windows 8.1 system which had the Dell backup software and in that also there was failure indoing so.I have also asked the [question here](http://superuser.com/questions/833389/unable-to-create-a-rescue-disk-along-with-the-drivers-in-the-dell-backup-and-rec)

Answer (score 0):

Look for your `servicetag` (7 letters tag). Its on the bottom of your notebook or under the battery. Enter the servicetag [here](http://www.dell.com/servicetag) and you will get the drivers for exactly your notebook. The most important driver is the network / wlan driver. Wihout it you won't be able to download a forgotten driver.

Comment: thank you for you reply but i have already done that.Plz check in my question with my link" I have gone through the Dell.com/support for the drivers but can't decide as to which one should be downloaded.(34 drivers in total)."

Comment: Check the screen shot. This is what  get after entering the service tag.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the latest driver for your system for each of the available devices in your system, including, but not limited to:

- chipset
- ethernet
- wireless ethernet
- audio
- video
- seriel ata (SATA) controller
- modem
- mouse, keyboard & input device

Make sure you get a driver version compatible with the version of Windows you're running. (i.e. Windows 7 64-bit)

Comment: ok and how do i find the available h/w for which i need to download the drivers(isn't there any driver update s/w or it should be done manually).Also what if there are two drivers under a single category.

Comment: like under the Network i have    1)Dell Wireless 1501/1503/1701 Half Mini Card Driver  2)Dell Wireless 1702 802.11 b/g/n, Bluetooth 3.0+HS Driver 3)Realtek RTL8111E-VB Gigabit and RTL8105E-VB 10/100 Ethernet Controller Driver and so on 9 files are there now in that which one will be suitable for me

Comment: The easiest way to tell which device is in your PC is to look up the model on the website by `servicetag` as suggested by `boboes`. Alternatively you can have a look in Windows Device Manager, and you will be able to see the device names there. Device Manager can be accessed through `Start > Control Panel > Device Manager`. If you are not comfortable with this, there's a bit of further reading [here](http://www.7tutorials.com/find-missing-drivers-hidden-components-device-manager).

Comment: The tutorial cleared my doubt regarding the hardware on Windows but it left a new doubt whether to update the hardware drivers by the os /visit hardware site and download the drivers.

Comment: The reason I didn't settle for boboes post was after entering the service tag i got 34 drivers and under the network driver's it shows 7out of 9 to be simmilar

Comment: the device manager will show only if the driver is missing or not.But not whether the driver is to be updated because when i selected for all available h/w check for updates>automatic as given by the tutorial it didn't give any single update to download.